# Php: How to ignore newline in Regex

Tags: php, regex

I've already found a lot of `stackoverflow questions` about this topic. But I cannot find out the solution out of these questions for my problem.

I have the following html:

```
<p><a name="first-title"></a></p>
<h3>First Title</h3>
<h2><a href='#second'>Second Title</a></h2>
<h3>Third Title</h3>
```

I want to find out the `<h3>` prepended by `</a></p>`. In this case, the output should be:

```
<h3>First Title</h3>
```

So I implement the following regular expression;

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=<\/a><\/p>)<h3>(.+?)<\/h3>/s',$html,$data);
```

The above **regular expression** cannot output anything from the above **html**. But if I remove the **newlines** from the html, the above regular expression can correctly output my desire result.

I would not like to remove **newlines** from the **html** if possible. How should I develop **regular expression** to ignore the **newlines** from the source string?

Please, help me.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454. Regexes are NOT the way to parse HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here comes the use of [`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html), since you can't use qunatifiers inside the lookaround assertions.

```
preg_match_all('/<\/a><\/p>\s*\K<h3>(.+?)<\/h3>/s',$html,$data);
```

or just put `\n` char inside the lookbehind.

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=<\/a><\/p>\n)<h3>(.+?)<\/h3>/s',$html,$data);
```